# How to use R to build a small prediction Model for Event X, based on past Questions A-V

Tags: r, time-series

What am I trying to do: Build a small prediction model, to help me forecast an evaluation Event X, based on previous Datapoints/Questions.

I'm dealing with a wide dataset for ~60 Locations. Each Location is being asked several Questions (some more frequent then others) over a period of time. Then on the 2022-11-30 there is an Evaluation Event X. Now using some sort of Model/ML Algorithm I would like to find out which prior Question Result, pattern etc. is the best predictor of this Evaluation Event X.

My Data Structure looks like this:

| Location | Date | Question 1 | ... | Question 30 (Evaluation EVENT X) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-11-30 | NA | NA | 3 |
| A | 2022 -10-15 | 2 | NA | NA |
| ... | ... | NA | 3 | NA |

So every question is (mostly) recorded on a seperate Date, therefore all the other columns are (mostly) NA on that specific date.

What should my approach now be? Regular correlations failed for me as the observations are not in the same row...

Appreciate your help a lot!

I tried running regular linear models, but always failed due to the correlation matrices not being able to be calculated.